# Polarion: Is it possible to create custom jobs to be used by the scheduler

Tags: alm, polarion

I know about the [preconfigured jobs](https://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.polarion.xray.doc.user%2Fguide%2Fxid1552819.html) that exist for polarion. I now would like to add a custom job to delete specific work items that are created before a specific date. Exactly like the "[polarion.jobs.testruns.delete](https://docs.plm.automation.siemens.com/content/polarion/20/help/en_US/user_and_administration_help/administrators_guide/configure_testing/configure_cleanup_of_old_test_runs.html)" job but for other work items.

Is it possible to create a custom job that i can add to the scheduler in polarion? And if yes, how would i approach such a task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This has been answered [here](https://community.sw.siemens.com/s/question/0D54O00007MgT2CSAV/is-it-possible-to-create-custom-jobs-to-be-used-by-the-scheduler) in the Siemens Polarion forum.**

> Chapter 6.1.3 of the SDK Guide provides instructions and an example on
> how to create custom jobs. The SDK Guide can be found [here](https://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/sdk.pdf).